# Fishers-R-to-Z - published study reporting value I can't replicate

Tags: fisher-transform

I am reading a paper that reported a significant difference in correlation between age and some measure between groups.  It looks like they calculated the Fisher's-R-to-Z wrong?  I wonder if someone could check my math?

Group 1: R = .618, p = .001,  n = 24

Group 2: R = .258, p = .223, n = 24

The researchers reported a Z = 3.23 and p = .001

When I do the calculation online through http://vassarstats.net/rdiff.html I get Z= 1.48, P = .1389

Am I wrong or did this study report the wrong Z values?

I am trying to do the same analysis and I want to make sure that I am calculating the Z value correctly.

Comment: It's possible to get this value if the correlations are dependent (see: http://quantpsy.org/corrtest/corrtest2.htm) .

Comment: Groups were independent - Group 1 NCs, Group 2 = individuals with ASD

Comment: How is that link relevant? It's an app for comparing two correlation coefficients, but you cite statistics for comparing each one to zero.  [Here are the two Z-scores computed for you.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Barctanh%5B+.618%5D+*+sqrt%5B24+-+3%5D,+arctanh%5B.258%5D+*+sqrt%5B24-3%5D%7D)

Comment: Ok, so the calculations provided by the previous website vassarstats.net (above) are incorrect?  I am trying to compare the correlation coefficent of one group to the correlation coefficent of another group to determine if there are statistical differences between these correlations between groups.  Would it be safe to apply your formula to this problem??

Comment: The calculation performed by that website are irrelevant: they apply to a different problem.  "My formula" is the Fisher transformation.